# How can I have prototype function as parameters?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Let say:

```
function MapMePls (str, func, ...args) {
  return str.func(...args);
}

MapMePls('Hello World!', toLowerCase);
```

The `func` can be any prototype functions from `String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the name of the function as `string` and use `[]` syntax to access it. Also add a checking to be sure that the passed name is an **actual function name**.

```js
function MapMePls (str, func, ...args) {
  if(!str[func] || typeof str[func] !== 'function') {
      throw new Error('function does not exist');
  }

  return str[func](...args);
}

console.log(MapMePls('Hello World!', 'toLowerCase'));
```